# How to access another child class from parent in JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have my markup looks like:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 mainDiv">
    <div class="rowDiv"> <!--first row starts-->

        <div class="a1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown-container-skills">
                    <select class="dropdown-skills">
                        <option>Select Any</option>
                        <option value="S1">Skill 1</option>
                        <option value="S2">Skill 2</option>
                        <option value="S3">Skill 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="a1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown-container-topics">
                    <select class="dropdown-topics">
                        <option>Select Any</option>
                        <option value="T1">Topic 1</option>
                        <option value="T2">Topic 2</option>
                        <option value="T3">Topic 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div><!--first row ends-->

    <div class="rowDiv"> <!--second row starts-->

        <div class="a1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown-container-skills">
                    <select class="dropdown-skills">
                        <option>Select Any</option>
                        <option value="S1">Skill 1</option>
                        <option value="S2">Skill 2</option>
                        <option value="S3">Skill 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="a1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown-container-topics">
                    <select class="dropdown-topics">
                        <option>Select Any</option>
                        <option value="T1">Topic 1</option>
                        <option value="T2">Topic 2</option>
                        <option value="T3">Topic 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div><!--second row ends-->


</div>
```

I want something like when I select skill from first row it will update topics in the first row itself. Also when I select skill from second row it will update topics in second row and so on. I wrote the script for this as:

```
$('body').on('change', '.dropdown-skills', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'getTopics/' + $(this).val(),
          dataType : "html",
          success: function(response)
          {
            $(this).closest('.rowDiv').find('.dropdown-container-topics').html(response);

          }
    });
});
```

ie when I change class `dropdown-skills` it will get the topics as html from the controller function and it is then fed into class `dropdown-container-topics` of the current row.
But this is not working. How can it be done?

Comment: A good start would be to place your 'change' event handler onto your select elements and not on your document body

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Your code seems to work, i.e. it finds the corresponding `.dropdown-container-topics` and changes the inner HTML. Perhaps your controller isn't returning the correct HTML?

Comment: Hi, your ajax is not able to identify what is `$(this)` inside success function so you can simply save reference for `$(this)` in some variable outside ajax ie : `var selector =  $(this)` and use same inside success function `selector.closest('.rowDiv')...`

Comment: @Swati that solved the issue.